# Reading a github private raw file using python, returns source code not executing the code

Tags: python, github

I created a Python code and uploaded it to Github, okay now I have the raw file with the key, Now I wanna create a Python file on my pc that will import the code from Github and execute it and then convert it to .exe, I tried this code:

```py
import requests
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...../filename?key='
page = requests.get(url)
print (page.text)
```

Ok, but the result is that when I run the Python file, the source code appears for me and does not execute it.

what should I do?

Comment: Well, you can execute code from a string with `eval()`, but that doesn't help you with converting it anything into an exe... What's your end goal here?

Comment: Nah i'm don't ask about converting to exe, I'll do it later, I'm just trying to execute my Github raw on my .py file, can you clarify more about eval() please?

Comment: If you are trying to import code from github, take a look at [httpimport](https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport).  Be aware of the security implications of downloading and executing code.